# Boujou Tracking - FOV feels wrong

Tags: camera, video, tracking, motion-capture

For the past few years, I've been tracking shots from Boujou to Blender, using Blender 2.49B to 2.9 (Thats one of the best, non-bugged ways to transfer tracks). Though, shots like this where the "iron-man-arm" is flying towards the subject, **it feels so flat**! Why is there no sense of depth? From far away to up-close feels like a simple image getting scaled-up. Boujou wants to set the focal lenth to 73-ish in Blender- but makes the motion tracking points not line up with the footage. So once I manually change the focal-length to have the motion tracks line up perfectly with the footage, I get that loss of depth the camera had previously. In addition, the tracking-points line up with the exact focal-length my camera was filming at, so clearly me manually lining up the track is the right way to go- I think.

If you want to see the [HD-version](https://www.tiktok.com/@officialjadenwilliams/video/6865493869652364549?lang=en)

[image: Rendered, tracked shot]

Boujou focal length. Depth is there, tracks aren't.
[image: automated focal length]

Manually-changed focal length. Depth is flat, tracks are correct.
[image: manual change in focal length]

Comment: is the sensor size the same as in the tracking software? The lens would not cover the same field of view otherwise.

Comment: @susu I'll look into that, thanks.